# running sed with two instructions

Tags: bash, sed

I wanted to run these sed lines:

```
sed 's/\/1\/1/\/1/g' file -i && sed 's/\/2\/2/\/2/g' file -i
```

over a file like this:

```
chr9_paternal   126628489       126629719       616L7AAXX_HWUSI-EAS627_0005:1:1:1157:5733/1/1   0       +       126628489       126629719       255,0,0 2
       19,57   0,1173
chr20_paternal  34093622        34093697        616L7AAXX_HWUSI-EAS627_0005:1:1:1158:4527/1/1   0       +       34093622        34093697        255,0,0 1
       75      0
chr17_paternal  44627748        44633513        616L7AAXX_HWUSI-EAS627_0005:1:1:1158:5412/2/2   0       +       44627748        44633513        255,0,0 2
       36,40   0,5725
chr1_paternal   224204536       224204611       616L7AAXX_HWUSI-EAS627_0005:1:1:1158:2312/1   0       +       224204536       224204611       255,0,0 1
       75      0
chr7_paternal   132309510       132309585       616L7AAXX_HWUSI-EAS627_0005:1:1:1158:1687/2/2   0       +       132309510       132309585       255,0,0 1
       75      0
chr20_paternal  45708069        45708144        616L7AAXX_HWUSI-EAS627_0005:1:1:1158:13916/1  63      +       45708069        45708144        255,0,0 1
       75      0
chr9_paternal   134850662       134850737       616L7AAXX_HWUSI-EAS627_0005:1:1:1158:10141/1/1  72      +       134850662       134850737       255,0,0 1
       75      0
chrX_paternal   71603273        71603348        616L7AAXX_HWUSI-EAS627_0005:1:1:1158:8367/2   30      +       71603273        71603348        255,0,0 1
```

in order to get this output:

```
chr9_paternal   126628489       126629719       616L7AAXX_HWUSI-EAS627_0005:1:1:1157:5733/1   0       +       126628489       126629719       255,0,0 2
       19,57   0,1173
chr20_paternal  34093622        34093697        616L7AAXX_HWUSI-EAS627_0005:1:1:1158:4527/1   0       +       34093622        34093697        255,0,0 1
       75      0
chr17_paternal  44627748        44633513        616L7AAXX_HWUSI-EAS627_0005:1:1:1158:5412/2   0       +       44627748        44633513        255,0,0 2
       36,40   0,5725
chr1_paternal   224204536       224204611       616L7AAXX_HWUSI-EAS627_0005:1:1:1158:2312/1   0       +       224204536       224204611       255,0,0 1
       75      0
chr7_paternal   132309510       132309585       616L7AAXX_HWUSI-EAS627_0005:1:1:1158:1687/2   0       +       132309510       132309585       255,0,0 1
       75      0
chr20_paternal  45708069        45708144        616L7AAXX_HWUSI-EAS627_0005:1:1:1158:13916/1  63      +       45708069        45708144        255,0,0 1
       75      0
chr9_paternal   134850662       134850737       616L7AAXX_HWUSI-EAS627_0005:1:1:1158:10141/1  72      +       134850662       134850737       255,0,0 1
       75      0
chrX_paternal   71603273        71603348        616L7AAXX_HWUSI-EAS627_0005:1:1:1158:8367/2   30      +       71603273        71603348        255,0,0 1
```

But the file is pretty big and I don't want to read it twice. It is possible run a sed code that execute two instructions at once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `-e` to execute multiple expressions in one `sed` call:

```
sed -e <expr> -e <expr> -i <file>
```

Answer (score 5):

If I understood it correctly, you want to replace `/1/1` with `/1` and likewise, `/2/2` with `/2`:

```
sed -i 's:/1/1:/1:;s:/2/2:/2:' file
```

Use the colon `:` instead of `/` so you can avoid escaping.

Comment: OP didn't specify his sed version, but not all seds understand `;`

Comment: @Glenn: Thank you. I tested it (without the -i flag) under Mac, Redhat, and Ubuntu and they works fine, but you are correct. There are versions of sed that don't understand semicolon, in which case, the -e flags should be used.

Comment: @glennjackman: But you could compile Gnu-sed for Solaris, coulnd't you? Theoretically, at least.

Comment: @userunknown, of course. However I prefer less cryptic (IMO) languages. I'll use sed for very simple things, awk for somewhat more complex things, Perl or Tcl (depending on the context) for the next level, etc.

Answer (score 4):

In this example with just two edits to make, you can use `-e` or the semi-colon in between operations quite easily, as shown in other answers.  I have scripts with 10 or more `-e` options on successive lines.

If it gets more complex still (or you need to generate many mappings from some data), you can write a file and have `sed` read its instructions from the file with the `-f` option:

```
sed -f sed.script -i file
```